# How can I make tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two distinct scenarios.

One, where there is a many to many case, you must create a third table. But I'm not familiar with MySQL syntaxis.

[image]

Two, is this one:

[image]

How can I declare using SQL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MYSQL my create tables using the `CREATE TABLE` command. If you don't feel too confident to write your tables with that syntax, I'd suggest using a tool like the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.de/downloads/workbench/). That tool can greatly help you there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at [CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)